# Can any waterborne pathogens survive boiling?

Tags: water-purification, first-aid

I know that boiling does little to break down chemical contaminants or heavy metals. But I'm unsure if it kills all microbial life. Are there any waterborne illness-causing viruses/bacteria/protozoa/cysts that can survive boiling? And if so, how serious is the illness they cause?

Comment: I would like to point out that "boiling" is not actually a specific heat. You can boil water at extremely low heat if you are at high altitude.

Comment: Right, heavy metals can only break down by radioactive decay, and most isotopes not even that. (To be exact, shooting stuf into them, like neutrons, may actually help). It fascinates me that they can harm you and are basically indestructible...

Answer (score 18):

[This article](http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/3/355.full) (*) gives a good summary of the efficiency of boiling as a method for making water safe for consumption. In particular, Table 2 provides a summary of the temperature and time required to kill various micro-organisms.

> Sterilisation of water (killing all living containments) is not
>   necessary to make water safe to drink. For example, boiling may not be
>   effective against bacterial spores such as *Clostridium* which can
>   survive at 100°C (212°F), however, as *Clostridium* is not a
>   waterborne enteric (intestinal) pathogen, ingestion will not cause
>   infection.
>
> All waterborne enteric pathogens are quickly killed above 60°C
>   (140°F), therefore, although boiling is not necessary to make the
>   water safe to drink, the time taken to heat the water to boiling is
>   usually sufficient to reduce pathogens to safe levels. Allowing the
>   boiled water to cool slowly will also extend the exposure of
>   waterborne enteric pathogens to lethal temperatures.
>
> Boiling also gives a simple visual indicator that a high enough
>   temperature has been reached when a thermometer is not available.
>
> (*) Backer, H. Water Disinfection for International and Wilderness
>   Traveler. Clinical Infectious Diseases.  (2002) 34 (3): 355-364.
>   Available from: http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/3/355.full

Comment: What about Clostridium Botulinum? Ingestion of this bacteria can and frequently does give people botulism which can cause death if left untreated. That would appear to be counter to what that article is suggesting.

Comment: @BenAlabaster As I understand it, Clostridium spores are heat resistant but are not toxic by ingestion. Clostridium bacteria and botulism toxin which can be toxic by ingestion are easily destroyed by boiling water.

Answer (score 12):

Boiling kills everything -- giardia, cryptosporidium, other bacteria, and viruses. 185°F (85°C) for a few minutes will do it, and boiling for one minute will do it. (Boiling is lots of big bubbles, not just a few small bubbles on the side of the pot.)

[Some people recommend longer boiling times at higher altitudes](http://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/private/wells/disease/hepatitis_a.html) because water boils at cooler temperatures there.

(Source: Wilderness Medical Society, *The Backpacker's Field Manual* by Curtis)

Comment: I know there is some question whether you need 'minutes' or just bringing to a rolling boil is enough. I lean toward the latter, and have never had issues.

Comment: Not quite true... There are some bacteria that can survive boiling, but I seriously doubt you would ever find them in your traditional hiking water sources! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthermophile

Comment: There's one more caveat: While boiling kills most bacterias responsible for food-borne illnesses, boiling doesn't necessarily destroy their spores/toxins. One infamous example is botulism.

Comment: Note that the water must be **clean** to kill all bacteria, meaning that there cannot be particulates like silt, or any detritus within it. Bacteria and cryptosporidium can hide in those places, and survive the boiling process. So filter or settle your water if it is dirty, or boil for 15 minutes.

Comment: And what about eggs of roundworms (Ascaris lumbricoides) and other parasites? I've heard some of them are very hard to kill even by high temperature...

Comment: Clostridium Botulinum will survive to around 120 deg C

Comment: I know this answer is over 3 years old, but I can't help but point out that 185F (85C) isn't anywhere close to 140.6C. Incidentally, 140C liquid water would kill ANYTHING exposed to it, even if it survived the pressure necessary to raise the water's boiling point that high.

Comment: Clostridium botulinum can't make you sick by ingestion of the spores in drinking water, so that's not relevant here. The question is about waterborne illness, not food poisoning.

Comment: In spite of the eminent source xpda mentioned, I have to conscientiously downvote this answer as per Lagerbaer et al. Bacterial spores in particular can survive _well above_ 85 °C. It definitely doesn't kill 'everything'.

Answer (score 10):

Botulinum toxin is particularly tough, as is Bacillus cereus.  B. cereus is more likely found while camping.

But your goal is not so much to *kill* everything as reduce the level to the point where it does no harm.  The dust you breathe, the things you touch, and (yick!) the people you are with all bring various pathogens, as does your tap water and (often especially) bottled water. Do your best, and your body takes care of the rest.

Comment: +1 for the pragmatic view about "where it does no harm". But can you give more detail about pathogens in bottled water?!

Comment: From linked article: "The botulinum toxin is destroyed by boiling the food for 10 minutes." I've written it here, as the very important information

Comment: However, the staphylococcus toxin is heat-resistant: http://www.caes.uga.edu/departments/fst/extension/documents/FoodPoisoning-FoodInfection.pdf, http://www.rapidmicrobiology.com/test-methods/Bacterial-Toxins-Food.php

Comment: This answer is misleading because Bacillus doesn't cause disease through drinking water.

Answer (score 5):

Some types of spores can survive boiling. But they're either not disease-causing or they're not in any condition to make you sick as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia has some interesting points on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Boiling#For_making_water_potable):

> The elimination of micro-organisms by boiling follows first-order
>   kinetics—at high temperatures it is achieved in less time and at lower
>   temperatures, in more time. The heat sensitivity of micro-organisms
>   varies, at 70 °C (158 °F), **Giardia species (causes Giardiasis) can
>   take ten minutes for complete inactivation**, most intestine affecting
>   microbes and **E. coli (gastroenteritis) take less than a minute**; at
>   boiling point, Vibrio cholerae (cholera) takes ten seconds and
>   hepatitis A virus (causes the symptom of jaundice), one minute.
>   Boiling does not ensure the elimination of all micro-organisms; the
>   **bacterial spores Clostridium can survive at 100 °C (212 °F) but are
>   not water-borne or intestine affecting.** Thus for human health,
>   complete sterilization of water is not required.[3]
>
> The traditional advice of boiling water for ten minutes is mainly for
>   additional safety, since microbes start getting eliminated at
>   temperatures greater than 60 °C (140 °F) and bringing it to its
>   boiling point is also a useful indication that can be seen without the
>   help of a thermometer, and by this time, the water is disinfected.
>   Though the boiling point decreases with increasing altitude, it is not
>   enough to affect the disinfecting process.

Comment: The bolded material about Giardia isn't relevant, since it talks about 70 C, but the question is about boiling. The bolded material about Clostridium isn't relevant, because, as noted in the text, Clostridium doesn't cause disease in drinking water.