# How long does water need to be boiled for to kill all bacteria / viruses?

Tags: survival, water-purification

This has come up a few times in a few other questions, but I've heard varying opinions from different people in a number of answers and comments on here - some saying that just boiling for a moment is enough, others saying that to be sure you should boil for around 10 minutes, and others saying it doesn't matter how long you boil for because some bacteria can survive it with no problem.

So in short, how long should you boil water you've collected for to ensure it's safe to drink? (I'm discounting filtering like metals which boiling won't remove.) It'd be good if answers could be referenced / backed up since people do seem to have different ideas on the subject!

Comment: related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-the-safest-way-to-purify-water

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about where the water is being collected, but the unspoken assumption may be that backcountry water contains bacteria, viruses, or protozoan cysts capable of causing disease when you drink it. That's not true, as discussed in this answer to a related question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/4058/2169 . Of course boiling may still be wise at home after a natural disaster, in third-world travel, when hiking near livestock farms, or when the water is from an obviously untrustworthy backcountry source, such as a puddle full of mule poop.

Comment: Keep in mind that boiling only kills pathogens and destroys some toxins.  Toxins that are not destroyed by high heat will actually be *concentrated* by the boiling process, making the water less drinkable than it was before.  So exercise some care in choosing your water source.

Comment: Also related: [(191)](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/191/133)

Comment: It's unfortunate that the incorrect answer by Justin C has been accepted and is currently the most upvoted answer.

Comment: The checked answer is wrong. Government guidelines are designed for simplicity. [Safe Minimum Internal Temperature Chart](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/safe-minimum-internal-temperature-chart/ct_index) for cooking meat gives ridiculously high temperatures that instantly kill all bacteria, but also destroy perfectly good meat.  Lower temperatures for longer times are just as effective, but more complicated. Chicken breast at the recommended 74°C (165°F) is a chew-toy for your dog.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The EPA recommends boiling for one minute for most people, and three minutes for anyone above 5000ft or 1000m (sic) in elevation.

reference - https://www.epa.gov/ground-water-and-drinking-water/emergency-disinfection-drinking-water

That is what I have always done when backpacking. I don't boil for 10-20 minutes because it will kill my fuel supply and waste too much of the water. If I were camping and had plenty of fuel I might boil longer to be safe.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the altitude issues.  Water boils at decreasing temperatures as altitude increases, but that doesn't mean pathogens die at those lower temperatures.

Comment: @Matthew - I'm not sure that's true. My understanding is that they are killed by the water inside them reaching a temperature that forces a state change (liquid to gas). Not 100% sure of that, but that's how I understand it.

Comment: @Greg.Ley, no.  As shown by [this](http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/3/355/F2.expansion.html) graph linked by Graham, different pathogens die at different temperatures (and various times *at* that temperature).  No mention is made of altitude or phase change, and most temperatures are far lower than sea-level boiling point.  Of course, boiling at sea level for sufficient time is one way to achieve those times and temperatures.

Comment: That looks right. Makes it easy, too, because unless you're boiling above 14000 ft you'll kill anything by the time it hits boiling (depending on how you interpret Hep A).

Comment: A recommendation by an agency like the EPA isn't the same as scientific evidence. As explained in the correct answers by Graham and Michael Pryor, the scientific evidence is that all disease-causing organisms are dead long before the water reaches a boil.

Comment: @Ben - I never claimed it was scientific evidence. The poster requested references. I provided the reference and included my personal experience. I like Graham's answer so I gave it a vote myself.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. Both Graham's answer and Michael Pryor's answer give correct information from reliable scientific sources.

Comment: It's safe to drink as soon as it reaches boiling poi 300nt, there's no real evidence to support that b2o3ilin//.

Comment: Honestly, I just use a portable filter. Very easy and I don’t have to worry about pathogens or heavy metals. Makes the worst water taste pretty good. I use the Sawyer Mini.

Comment: @M.Mat filters are not sufficient against viruses

Comment: Depends on the filter! Seriously. Most decent 2 stage filters DO clear many common virus. Don’t argue in the comments please.

Answer (score 48):

[This article](http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/3/355.full) (*) gives a good summary of the efficiency of boiling as a method for making water safe for consumption. In particular, Table 2 provides a summary of the temperature and time required to kill various micro-organisms.

A distinction should be drawn between killing *all* pathogens and making water safe to drink. Sterilisation of water (killing all living containments) is not necessary to make water safe to drink. For example, boiling may not be effective against bacterial spores such as *Clostridium* which can survive at 100°C (212°F), however, as *Clostridium* is not an enteric (intestinal) pathogen, ingestion will not cause infection.

All enteric pathogens are quickly killed above 60°C (140°F), therefore, although boiling is not necessary to make the water safe to drink, the time taken to heat the water to boiling is usually sufficient to reduce pathogens to safe levels. Allowing the boiled water to cool slowly will also extend the exposure of enteric pathogens to lethal temperatures.

Boiling also gives a simple visual indicator that a high enough temperature has been reached when a thermometer is not available.

(*) Backer, H. Water Disinfection for International and Wilderness Traveler. Clinical Infectious Diseases.  (2002) 34 (3): 355-364. Available from: http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/3/355.full

Comment: +1 for giving a reliable scientific source and for a correct explanation of why it's not necessary to kill all heat-resistant spores

Comment: Note that in Table 2 of the article, some temperatures as high as 98 C are listed, but that doesn't mean that lower temperatures were found to fail. The table just lists some temperatures that were found to succeed. This answer gives the correct interpretation, which is that all disease-causing organisms are dead long before the boiling point is reached.

Comment: +1 but note that the article implies (to a skim reading at least) the filtration or sedimentation is necessary as a first step - I'm not sure how much of a protective/insulating effect particles of dirt have given the time at temperature in complete immersion, but it's also going to be a lot nice to drink.

Comment: I have a large bit of dirt in the water, just getting the water to boiler point, my not get the inside of the dirt hot enough unless you boil for some time.

Comment: @BenCrowell, I agree that this answer gives the right advice for most drinking water purposes, but it's not true that `all disease-causing organisms are dead long before the boiling point is reached`. That's why hospitals use autoclaves and autoclave for 3min at 134°C or 15 min at 121°C. Admittedly, this is not relevant - or rather, not practical - for outdoor purposes. (The Wiki articles on Prions or Autoclaves give a good overview on the topic).

Answer (score 8):

0 minutes.

> “According to the Wilderness Medical Society, water temperatures above 160° F (70° C) kill all pathogens within 30 minutes and above 185° F (85° C) within a few minutes. So in the time it takes for the water to reach the boiling point (212° F or 100° C) from 160° F (70° C), all pathogens will be killed, even at high altitude.  To be extra safe, let the water boil rapidly for one minute, especially at higher altitudes since water boils at a lower temperature (see page 68.)”

Source: http://www.princeton.edu/~oa/manual/water.shtml

[More info on this survival blog](http://survivaltopics.com/that-water-is-unsafe-to-drink/).

Comment: -1 Boiling certainly reduces the viability of bacteria and viruses, but to say "All pathogens will be killed" is incorrect. Most prions and many bacterial and fungal spores are resistant to the temperatures reached by boiling.

Comment: I think we need some scholarly references here, because the Wilderness Medicine Institute also says to bring water just to a boil to be safe. It is conflicting, so I think we need better sources to answer this question accurately.

Comment: @Greg.Ley probably. I mean, this question in itself is obviously hard to answer and the OP admitted that.  Different experts feel differently about it. Maybe the answer is, AT LEAST boil it, and keep boiling the longer you can.  If it's an emergency, just drink it once it boils. If you have ten min, let it go.

Comment: http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/page/water-treatment.htm

Comment: I believe the CDC recommendation is based on the fact that your average person doesn't know what "boil" means, not because it is actually necessary. I have some references for that if it's appropriate.

Comment: @Greg.Ley -- From a scientific standpoint you are absolutely correct that the minute is not necessary.  From an applied science in the wild standpoint, where I am in the woods with no thermometer, I'm going to err on the side of using that minute to make sure I don't get Hepatitis (which can require temperatures up to 98C to kill).

Comment: @Russell - Fair enough. I would particularly take that precaution if I were with a group of newbies (tend to have worse hygiene).

Comment: I added the rest of the quote, since they do say to boil longer at higher altitudes.

Comment: @Graham: As you noted in your own answer, the viability of the organisms you mentioned at boiling temperatures doesn't matter, because they don't cause disease that can be transmitted by drinking them in water.

Comment: blog link is dead

Comment: @MichaelPryor: *this question in itself is obviously hard to answer and the OP admitted that. Different experts feel differently about it.* Nope, there is no scientific controversy. "To be extra safe..." doesn't indicate there is any controversy about whether it's necessary to keep the water at 100 C for a certain amount of time. It indicates the concern that people might see a few bubbles coming up and incorrectly interpret that as boiling.

Comment: @RussellSteen: *Hepatitis (which can require temperatures up to 98C to kill).* Not true. Is this based on the table linked to from Graham's answer? Take another look. There are two references with two very different temperatures. These are not conflicting claims about what temperature is needed. They're simply empirical verifications that certain temperatures suffice. The paper given as the reference for the 98 C figure is available here: http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/ijlink?linkType=PDF&journalCode=jinfdis&resid=122/5/432 They didn't try lower temperatures.

Comment: @BenCrowell -- No, the statement was based on research I did at the time of clinical studies of the viability of various pathogens.  Off the top of my head that was based on a paper I got from the CDC.  I don't have it saved anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**The adequate minimum is 1-2 minutes** (100C water at the sea level). Mind the altitude. To kill bacteria you need a combination of temperature and time. At some altitudes (miles), without a pressurizer, you just can't kill some resilient strains in a reasonable time (low boiling temperature). Use other disinfection methods in addition.

*Why no less?*

For this method, you just need to know the local boiling temperature. Any pre-boiling temperature demands a thermometer to be sure that you're heating the water as intended. And the 1-2 minutes are enough to assure that it was boiling, not -5 -7C from the boiling point near the surface or so while you're thinking there was a full volume already boiled.

*Why 1-2 min. is safe enough at most elevations?*

See the tables about temperatures for pathogen killing and boiling temperature at different altitudes.
https://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/Boiling_water_01_15.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_cooking

**The maximum is 30 min.** It's for Anthrax as an edge case, again 100C at the sea level. The most important thing - it's a misconception that 70C for 30 minutes; 85° C for 2 minutes, or alike low energy procedures are ultimate protection. It's a somewhat recommendation for your protection on average, not a guarantee. It isn't killing everything, just lowering the most common harmful pathogens (including parasites, viruses, etc., excluding spores and toxins) to safe for a healthy individual levels. Alas, 30 min 100C boiling either won't kill everything, but it's already a paranoid level of heating.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrax

You can meet something like this bacterium in the wilderness; however, most of the time you will not.

**Decide yourself.**